# using jquery in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I was working on angularjs and i got strucked in using jquery with angularjs.
Here is my html code.....

```
 <div class="packery ">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h4"></div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item w4"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h4"></div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item w4"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

here is my js code............

```
$( function() {


  var packery = $('.packery').packery();

  console.log(packery);

  packery.on( 'click', function( event ) {
    // remove clicked element
    packery.packery( 'remove', event.target );
  });
});
```

Please help me convert this jquery code to work in angularjs. I am new to jquery, I tried many ways to solve this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is `packery` a JQuery plugin?

Comment: yes it was packery jquery plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have included jQyery

```
       $.noConflict();
       jQuery(function() {
           jQuery('.packery').on('click',function(){
              jQuery(this).remove();
           });
       });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvo014u8/)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i m getting an error like $ is not defined. how to make use of this code in angular..                                                          $( function() {
var packery = $('.packery').packery();

  console.log(packery);

  packery.on( 'click', function( event ) {
    // remove clicked element
    packery.packery( 'remove', event.target );
  });
});

Comment: This why I said, did you included jQuery in document head. also check if $ is not used. I am editing my answer

Comment: You need to add jQuery library specifying the path of the source, something like this `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`. This will download the file from jquery's cdn but you can give the local path in your project

Answer (score 1):

For a simple click event you need ng-click within your template described  at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

No need for jQuery in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply remove the clicked element, use this:

Your HTML:

```
<div class="packery">
   <div class="item" data-ng-click="remove($event)"></div>
   <div class="item h4" data-ng-click="remove($event)"></div>
   .......
</div>
```

Your Controller:

```
function myController( $scope ){
   $scope.remove=function($event){ 
       $event.target.remove();    
  }       
}
```

Check our the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0op35zo/) example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for an Angular directive. You can use an html attribute to specify which element the jQuery plugin should be applied to:

```
angular.module("mymod")
.directive("packery", function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $('[packery]').packery().on('click', function(event){
        $(element).packery('remove', event.target);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then, whenever you want this jQuery plugin to be applied to an element, you simply give that element the packery attribute:

```
<div packery>...</div>
```